# How do I list ALL IPA groups on Linux

Tags: active-directory, redhat, freeipa

I can get a list of groups on a linux server with the `getent group` command. However that only gives me local groups in the /etc/group file.

The server is connected to IPA that is used to create active directory groups. How can I get a list of groups IPA/Active Directory groups on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `ipa group-find` with no other arguments will display all user groups.

Comment: OK cool. thank you. I'm getting this response back: `ipa: ERROR: did not receive Kerberos credentials`. How do I enter credentials? I also tried this: `ipa show-group --password` and that did not work. I know the password. How do I enter my credentials?

Comment: Are you not logged in as a domain user? If not, you will have to login or `kinit` as a domain user.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was trying as root. That worked. I appreciate the tip!